# F# type provider FSharpX.ExcelFile and strange type errors trying to construct on a different input

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

I have a user-editable Excel file in a document repository that defines some inputs for an F# program. I'd like to read it using something F#-y, so I thought I would try out FSharpX and their ExcelFile type provider.

## What works

The provider is installed via NuGet and enabled, and this works:

```
open FSharpX
type Example = ExcelFile<"example.xlsx", "Worksheet1", true>
let file = new Example()
for row in File.Data do ......
```

## What doesn't

However, when I try to initialize the constructor with a different file (one I pull out of a database at runtime and stash in a temporary location), I get a really strange type error.

```
let file = new Example(@"c:\temp\path\to.xlsx")
```

results in

> The type provider 'FSharpx.TypeProviders.ExcelProvider+ExcelProvider'
>   reported an error in the context of provided type
>   'FSharpx.ExcelFile,filename="example.xlsx",sheetname="Worksheet1",forcestring="True"',
>   member '.ctor'. The error: Type mismatch when splicing expression into
>   quotation literal. The type of the expression tree being inserted
>   doesn't match the type expected by the splicing operation. Expected
>   'System.String', but received type
>   'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]'. Consider
>   type-annotating with the expected expression type, e.g., (%% x :
>   string) or (%x : string).  Parameter name: receivedType

## Huh?

I have no idea where the  tuple it's talking about could be coming from, and I don't have any other ideas about how to initialize this.

**Bonus question**: What if I wanted to vary over the worksheet name at runtime? The existing FSharpx provider does not seem to allow that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in the provider, not your code.  The provided constructor is using the filename you passed in, but the underlying code expects a filename and a workbook name (that's where the tuple ought to come from).

Comment: OK, just checking, I thought I was crazy or doing something wrong. Will file a bug.

Comment: This bug has been fixed: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/commit/e9912d9cb68cedd723e351748c47f9fefc7bbb3d (see line 154)

Answer (score 4):

Does appear to be a bug. The provided constructor accepting a single filename parameter does not call the internal constructor correctly in the quotation:

```
ty.AddMember(ProvidedConstructor([ProvidedParameter("filename", typeof<string>)], InvokeCode = fun [filename] -> <@@  ExcelFileInternal(%%filename) @@>))
....
type  ExcelFileInternal(filename, sheetorrangename)
```

I forked the FSharpx.Excel type provider a while ago, to modify it so that uses ClosedXML (as opposed to office interop), if the file is >= office 2007 (which I note your workbook is). I Also made a few changes to the API, exposing the worksheets (and/or ranges) as provided types, a 'Rows' provided type, and 'Row{n}' types.

```
type exc = ExcelFile<"C:\\temp\\Template.xlsx",false>
let file = new exc(@"C:\\temp\\Book.xlsx")
for row in file.Sheet1.Rows do
    printfn "%s" row.BID
let sht1Row1Col20 = file.Sheet1.Row1.BID
```

I'm afraid there is no 'Sheets' provided type, though, so you can't vary over the worksheet name at runtime. There is a string[] 'SheetAndRangeNames' type, but that's not going to be much use to you. Should not be particularly tricky to implement, however. You can find it here:

https://github.com/bennylynch/ExcelTypeProvider/

Comment: Thanks Ben! I think you should get them to pull your change, anything that avoids interop is *great*... This isn't super high on my priority list, but maybe I'll fork your fork and keep adding stuff to it sometime.

Comment: Was always meaning to, but never got round to it .... and I suspect it will be somewhat out of sycn now. Think I'll fork the latest, update it, and send a pull request .... now that  I know it'll be of use. Just hope they don't openly laugh at my code .....